# How do I remove unwanted areas while keeping the animated keyframes and wav in sync?

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, sound

I recorded a motion-capture along with voice as fbx and wav. How do I remove unwanted time periods while keeping the animated keyframes and wav in sync?

3DS MAX 2012 is being used. Standard plugins are being used.

Example: I want to remove long pauses manually in which the character neither moves nor speaks.

See this, the crossed areas should be removed:

[image]

Comment: More details might be required before we can give you a specific, detailed answer for your tool and setup. You've tagged the question [tag:3dsmax], but which version and which plugins are you using? If you want a general-procedure response, though, then I would try noting or marking specific keyframes in both the audio and animation to synchronize the audio, then hedging it until it sounds all right, similar to using a [clapperboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapperboard) in film.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja updated. Also: What do you mean by "hedging it"?

Comment: I assume that manually playing around with the markers until it works right.  In other news, if the animation is compressed and the audio is compressed then areas of no activity compress really very well... in which case removing these gaps may be wasted effort better spent towards compressing the data.

Comment: @PatrickHughes The reason is not disk space. It is rendering time. Because useless parts would be rendered and cut out later.